# Dynamic DropDownMenu in extjs

Tags: extjs, drop-down-menu

I have a 2 DropDownBoxes, where 1 of the drop box value is depanded on the selected value of the first.

How do i create a dynamic store in the second DropDownBoxes.

This is the code:

```
{
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            displayField: 'vendor_name',
                            typeAhead: true,
                            mode: 'local',
                            triggerAction: 'all',
                            emptyText:'Choose vendor...',
                            selectOnFocus:true,
                            fieldLabel: 'Vendor Name',
                            margin: 10,
                            id: 'txtBidVendor',
                            labelWidth: 100,
                            store:  Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                                fields:[
                                    {name: 'vendor_name'}
                                ],
                                proxy: {
                                    type: 'ajax',
                                    timeout: 120000,
                                    url: 'GetVendors.jsp',
                                    reader: {
                                        type: 'json',
                                        root: 'data',
                                        successProperty: 'success'
                                    }
                                },
                                autoLoad: true
                            })
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            displayField: 'rate_desc',
                            typeAhead: true,
                            mode: 'local',
                            triggerAction: 'all',
                            emptyText:'Choose Quality...',
                            selectOnFocus:true,
                            fieldLabel: 'Vendor Quality',
                            margin: 10,
                            id: 'txtBidVendorQuality',
                            labelWidth: 100,
                            store:  Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                                fields:[
                                    {name: 'rate_desc'}
                                ],
                                proxy: {
                                    type: 'ajax',
                                    timeout: 120000,
                                    url: 'GetVendorQuality.jsp?' + Ext.urlEncode({'bid_vendor': Ext.getCmp('txtBidVendor').value}), 
                                    reader: {
                                        type: 'json',
                                        root: 'data',
                                        successProperty: 'success'
                                    }
                                },
                                autoLoad: true
                            })
                        },
```

I get the error: "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined " ,in the line where i try getting "Ext.getCmp('txtBidVendor').value"

Answer (score 1):

About what you are trying to accomplish here I have two considerations:

1. The error here is that you are trying to access to the **txtBidVendor** component at definition time (it doesn't exists), when you send a configuration object (like these two comboboxes here) you are **not actually creating them**, but just setting the initial configuration  that will be used by its parent for later instantiation.
2. What I think you are trying to do is to change the query parameter value for the store, when the selection changes on **txtBidVendor** combobox. To accomplish that, you must **listen for the selection event** of the first combobox and then modify and **reload the store of the second one**. Something like this:

> ```
> {
>     xtype: 'combobox',
>     displayField: 'vendor_name',>         
>     emptyText: 'Choose vendor...',
>     selectOnFocus: true,
>     fieldLabel: 'Vendor Name',
>     id: 'txtBidVendor',
>     store: vendorStore,
>     listeners: {
>         select: function (combo, records, eOpts) {
>             var record = records[0]; // just want the first selected item
>
>             rateStore.getProxy().extraParams.bid_vendor = record.get('vendor_name');
>             alert('Store will load now with bid_vendor =' + record.get('vendor_name'));
>             rateStore.load();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

*For sake of readability it will be good idea to take store definition out of the components definition itself also*.  Here you can find a [**working sample of it**](http://jsfiddle.net/8h4kH/).

Hope it helps.